# Does this experimental design avoid pseudo-replication?

Tags: experiment-design, pseudorepliction

I’m looking at a data set where 15 properties undertaking new management practices are sampled over three seasons. Measurements taken include variables such as vegetation cover and canopy cover. Quadrats have been randomly allocated across these properties, and the number of quadrats per site is related to property size. Every season the placement of the quadrat is randomly generated again. Therefore, different arrangment of quadrats at different times within each property.

Could these measurements be treated as individual samples or replicates, or is this entering pseudo-replication territory?